# Suddenly unable to share WordPress link on Facebook

Tags: links, facebook

I was able to share links from my WordPress blog on Facebook with no issues up till about a month ago. Previously, the abstract and featured image turned up fine, but now only the link shows up. I've tried adding OG meta tags to my `functions.php` but it is not solving the problem. Using a plugin didn't help either.

I ran the facebook object debugger and I got a response code: 200 Error:

> Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

Here is a [sample link](http://www.delicacious.com/?p=1402).

Comment: Your page took a minute and a half to fully load, it appears linkwithin's `widget.js` is delaying page load for some reason, I suggest disabling that and testing again.

Comment: Hi Milo, thanks for the suggestion. I disabled it but it still doesn't solve the link problem on facebook. The site does load alot faster though.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. It was something with the permalinks. I changed the permalinks structure and suddenly it works.

For anyone who may have a similar problem, try going to settings under wordpress --> permalinks and try changing the permalink structure. I changed mine from day and name to post name and now facebook can recognise the links.